# Is it possible to have a separate unity launcher for each virtual workspace?

Tags: unity, 13.10, launcher, virtualdesktop

I was wondering if there was a relatively straight forward (or not) way to have virtual launchers for each virtual workspace.

I dislike the way a virtual workspace, say 3, will jump to workspace 1 if I try to open a new application that is already open on 1.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean workspace? The thing where you can switch around desktops using CTRL+ALT+Direction?

Comment: Yes, I will correct my post.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have separate launchers for each virtual workspace in Unity.

But you can use the middle mouse button to always open a new application on the current workspace (if the application allows this) instead of jumping to an existing one.

Comment: Are there other graphical shells which would provide this functionality?